# Book where humans are interplanetary, and have developed telepathy

Tags: story-identification, novel, telepathy

This book takes place in a futuristic setting. Humans have developed telepathy and/or psychic links and maybe other mental abilities.  People are interplanetary.  I think there was something about after birthing a certain number of children; any more after that would be owned by the government or something, similar to that plot element from *Enders Game*, but that is not the book.  The book starts with a guy in some place, or on a planet by himself, thinking or talking to himself about the state of things etc. which basically explains parts of the setting, and then he gets some kind of telepathic sign or signal from one of his siblings I believe.  That may be where I left off.

Anyone know the book?  I do not know exactly when it was published, however 2006 or before.  Thanks.  I'm not sure if it is a very well known book, it may not be.  I did find it once many years ago online somehow but have not had such luck again.

Comment: When you say interplanetary, is humanity still restricted to the solar system, or is it interstellar?  Is everyone telepathic, or just special people?  Are there aliens?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?

Comment: I dont know if interstellar or not. I dont know if everyone is or just certain people, or possibly just siblings have a psychic link. The person he gets a message from is I believe a sibling of his. It might be asking him to go somewhere because something is wrong with the person. The guy is somewhere, alone, maybe a planet, or moon, or maybe he even went back to earth but the person he is recieving a message about is elsewhere in space. The title is a word and somehow alludes to mental, psychic, mystic abilites in some way. Might start with an E.  Cover was not elaborate, had stars or lights.

Comment: Parts of this remind me of books in McCaffrey's *Pegasus* books. Psychic talents and population control, but the population control was in the book where humanity was just building space stations, not yet interplanetary.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the Robert Heinlein novel, *"Time for the Stars"*? It was published in 1956 so it's much older than 2006. Also, it's been a long time since I read it but I don't remember the framing device of an adult remembering the events of the novel.

Here's the plot description from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_for_the_Stars):

> The Long Range Foundation (LRF), a non-profit organization that
> funds     expensive, long-term projects for the benefit of mankind,
> has built a dozen     exploratory torchships to search for habitable
> planets to colonize. The     vessels can continually accelerate, but
> cannot exceed the speed of light, so     the voyages will last many
> years. Each starship has a much larger crew than     necessary to
> maintain a more stable, long-term shipboard society, as well as     to
> provide replacements for the inevitable deaths.
>
> The LRF has found that some **twins and triplets can communicate
> with each     other telepathically. The process seems instantaneous
> and unaffected by     distance, making it the only practical means of
> communication for ships     traveling many light-years away from
> Earth**. Before announcing the discovery,     the Foundation first
> recruits as many of these people as it can. Testing     shows that
> teenagers Tom and Pat Bartlett have this talent, and both sign     up.
> Pat, the dominant twin, manipulates things so that he gets selected as
> the crew member, much to Tom's annoyance. However, Pat does not really
> want     to leave and his subconscious engineers a convenient accident
> so that Tom     has to take his place at the last minute.

Comment: In *Time for the Stars*, over population of the Earth was a driving force behind the need to explore the stars.  The twins Pat and Tom put their parents "one over the limit" for allowed children - there is mention of their father being stubborn and resisting the state control of child birth.  There's also mention of the family paying extra taxes because of the extra child, with money always being scarce from the extra taxes.  There's also mention of Tom and Pat (somewhat) good naturedly joking between themselves about which one was the superfluous one.

Comment: @JRE Obviously been too long since I read it, or (as a teen) I glossed over the intro stuff and concentrated on the juicy parts -- telepathy testing and the actual star travel and exploration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are remembering the first book in [The Rowan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rowan) series. The telepaths in this series are rated from T12 to T1 on strength, with the strongest being known as T1 Primes. They are capable of gestalt mind melds to boost their power as well. The first book goes into dystopian population controls a little bit, but the thread is dropped as the series continues I believe.